# Python Requests post on a site not working

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape property information from https://www.ura.gov.sg/realEstateIIWeb/resiRental/search.action using Python Requests. Using Chrome I have inspected the POST request and emulated it using requests. I use sessions to maintain cookies. When I try my code, the return from the website is "missing parameters in search query" so obviously something is wrong with my requests (though it is not obvious what).

Doing some digging there was one cookie that I did not get when doing request.get on the search side, so I added that manually. Still no go. I tried emulating the request headers exactly as well, still does not return the correct results.

The only time I have gotten it to work is when I manually copy the cookies from my browser to the Python request object.

```
url = 'https://www.ura.gov.sg/realEstateIIWeb/resiRental/submitSearch.action;jsessionid={}'

values = {'submissionType': 'pn',
          'from_Date_Prj': 'JAN-2014',
          'to_Date_Prj': 'JAN-2016',
          '__multiselect_projectNameList': '',
          'selectedProjects': '10 SHELFORD',
          '__multiselect_selectedProjects': '',
          'propertyType': 'lp',
          'from_Date': 'JAN-2016',
          'to_Date': 'JAN-2016',
          '__multiselect_postalDistrictList': '',
          '__multiselect_selectedPostalDistricts': ''}
header1 = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6,no;q=0.4',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'www.ura.gov.sg',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6,no;q=0.4',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': 'www.ura.gov.sg',
    'Origin': 'https://www.ura.gov.sg',
    'Referer': 'https://www.ura.gov.sg/realEstateIIWeb/resiRental/search.action',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'
}

with requests.Session() as r:
    page1 = r.get('https://www.ura.gov.sg/realEstateIIWeb/resiRental/search.action', headers=header1)
    requests.utils.add_dict_to_cookiejar(r.cookies, {'BIGipServerpl-prod_iis_web_v4': '3334383808.20480.0000'})
    page2 = r.post(url.format(r.cookies.get_dict()['JSESSIONID']), data=values, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I would suggest you use [scrapy] (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) . Copying cookies is a breeze in scrapy. Internally scrapy uses requests library.

Comment: Are you sure there is no CSRF token in to the generated search form from the GET request?

Comment: I am not sure, is there a way to check that? I have focused on the request and response objects.